# Testing if double from textfield has a value or not

Tags: swift, if-statement

Trying to check if  double variable obtained from textfield has a value or not

let value:Double? = Double(valueTextfield.text!)

if(value.isEmpty()) X

if(value. == nil) X

if(value == 0) X

How do I do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use Double's init method and pass in the UITextField's text like this:

```
guard let text = valueTextfield.text, value = Double(text) else {
  // Here you can handle the case where the text is not a vaid Double string.
  return
}
// Here, value will be a valid Double type here if the textField contains a valid Double string.
```

Comment: `guard let text = valueTextfield.text, value = Double(text) else { return }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let doubleFromText = Double(textField.text!) {
    //use doubleFromText
} else {
    //could not make double 
}
```

For this, make sure `textField.text` is not `nil`. It's okay if it is "". It will go into the else part of the statement